# Is it possible to keep track of whois requests of a domain?

Tags: domain, whois, request-tracker

I'm interested in a domain, and want to buy it cheap.
Is it possible that I worsen my position in the discussion in the deal if I check it regularly with whois requests ?
Is it possible to show how many times somebody checked a domain whois records ?
What are the technical details needed to be able to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the domain holder, it's normally impossible to see at all that someone checked a whois record for this domain.

Comment: Think i hit 2 secs earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

As far i know the only guys who can monitor this are the sysadmins of the whois server which your client using. So the answer is no.
Please ellaborate what do you mean under technical requirements

Comment: So, if the person who wons the domain owns the whois server too, they can see ?
Who owns these whois servers usually ?

Comment: The domain registrar will typically run the relevant whois server.